# How to solve Property does not exist in type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using the library react-google-recaptcha to generate invisible ReCaptcha and I get the follow typescript error:

> Property 'execute' does not exist in type 'never'

This is the code:

```
  const recaptcha = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let token;
    if (recaptchaLoaded) {
      token = recaptcha.current?.execute();
    }
  }, [recaptchaLoaded]);
  
  
   <ReCAPTCHA
      ref={recaptcha}
      sitekey={SITE_KEY}
    />
```

**How can I type the .execute() so that this error doesn't happen anymore?** Or should I do it another way?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe by separating your code, a temp variable that would contain `recaptcha.current`, then a condition to test if you can call `execute` on it ?

Comment: const recaptcha = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null); try this ? const recaptcha = useRef<any>(null); or this ?

Comment: Using const recaptcha = useRef<any>(null) solved it!! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript the type of what the ref will refer to by providing a *type argument* to `useRef` (since TypeScript can't infer it from the initial value `null`). Assuming you're using [this `npm` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha), it appears you use the type of the component:

```
const recaptcha = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

More onto this; along with useRef(null) recaptcha const

```
const recaptcha = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);
//                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

in the recaptcha component, add an onChange event as in the below snippet.

```
  <ReCAPTCHA
    ref={recaptchaRef}
    onChange={handleCaptchaChange}
    sitekey="yourSiteKey"
  />


const handleCaptchaChange = () => {
    if (recaptchaRef.current) {
        const token = recaptchaRef.current.getValue();
        if (token)
            setSaveButtonDisabled(token.length <= 0);
    }
}
```

note the lines above
where you are checking for recaptcha.current  (if (recaptchaRef.current))
and check for null token (if (token))

the above will assert the possible null errors

[image: possible null error]

[image: clean code after assertions]